# Playwright C# - How to continue execute task, if my code cannot find the item

Tags: c#, playwright

How can I continue my performed `Task` when my code cannot find `possible-value` in, for example, a dropdown?

Example:

```cs
var dropdownSelector = page
    .Locator("[class='X']")
    .Locator("[class='Y']")
    .Locator("[class='possible-value']");

if (dropdownSelector.AllTextContentsAsync() != null)
{ 
    //do my code
}
else 
{ 
    //break this operation and continue execute next line of code
}
```

Let's assume that dropdown field is one of a few fields in editor. When I cannot find any element in my dropdown, my code will wait 30 seconds and throw a timeout exception.

Answer (score 2):

Playwright .Net uses asynchronous methods. Thus you need to [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) the method call. [Read more about asynchronous programming in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

It's also shown in [the Playwright docs](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/locators#lists)

```cs
var allTextContents = await dropdownSelector.AllTextContentsAsync();
```

If you don't `await`, the call will just return a `Task`, which is not `null`.

In many cases, asynchronous methods will have an (optional) `CancellationToken` parameter, but the Playwright .NET wrapper doesn't offer this ([see the source](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-dotnet/blob/f4be7830828257670f28d1ce1fd4e646db41320a/src/Playwright/Core/Locator.cs#L262)). You don't even get the option to set the timeout, like other methods have. So it will probably use the default of 30 seconds.

It's kind of awkward that you get the `TimeOutException`, as exceptions are not caught if you don't await the task.

The exception cannot be resolved. You can only catch it and discard it. There is no option to change the timeout, so if it times out you need another solution.

```cs
IReadOnlyList<string> allTextContents;
try
{
    allTextContents = await dropdownSelector.AllTextContentsAsync();
}
catch (TimeOutException)
{
    // cry
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply. But actually I don't want to use try / catch, I will try find other solution.